# ionic cordova barcodescanner not re-opening on IOS

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ngcordova

I've built an ionic app with ngCordova barcodescanner, it works, but I have one issue on IOS, if I kill the app when the barcodescanner is on (camera mode) I can't re-open the app (it's on but the barcode button don't respond and I can't see any issue in the log file) any more (even when I kill the background process), any ideas?

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            $cordovaBarcodeScanner
                .scan()
                .then(function(result) {
                    // Success! Barcode data is here                       
                        if (result.text.length > 0) {                               
                            SomeTest(result.text, function(err, result) {
                                if (!err) {
                                   // do something
                                }
                            });
                        } 

                }, function(error) {
                    // An error occurred
                });
        });
```

Comment: i have the same issue, are you already solve it?

Comment: Yes, the problem was not related to the Barcode, it was due to different behavior of Android and IOS with 'undefined' localStorage (the IOS couldn't load the controller so the barcode didn't react). Moreover, I had issues with IOS 8.3, and all I had to do is to upgrade the XCode and re init the plugin, hope it helps